# Remove text between () and []

Tags: python, python-2.7

I have a very long string of text with `()` and `[]` in it. I'm trying to remove the characters between the parentheses and brackets but I cannot figure out how.

The list is similar to this:

```
x = "This is a sentence. (once a day) [twice a day]"
```

This list isn't what I'm working with but is very similar and a lot shorter.

Comment: Please show what you've tried (by editing your question NOT by adding a comment), and people will point you in the right direction.

Comment: may `()` or `[]` be nested e.g., `"[a [(b] ([c))]]"`?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

This should work for parentheses. Regular expressions will "consume" the text it has matched so it won't work for nested parentheses.

```
import re
regex = re.compile(".*?\((.*?)\)")
result = re.findall(regex, mystring)
```

or this would find one set of parentheses, simply loop to find more:

```
start = mystring.find("(")
end = mystring.find(")")
if start != -1 and end != -1:
  result = mystring[start+1:end]
```

Comment: I don't know why this answer as marked as correct. The question in asking to *remove* text, not return it. I had the same need (remove text between certain chars) and @jvallver's answer helped me.

Comment: This achieves opposite than OP asked for

Answer (score 160):

You can use re.sub function.

```
>>> import re 
>>> x = "This is a sentence. (once a day) [twice a day]"
>>> re.sub("([\(\[]).*?([\)\]])", "\g<1>\g<2>", x)
'This is a sentence. () []'
```

If you want to remove the [] and the () you can use this code:

```
>>> import re 
>>> x = "This is a sentence. (once a day) [twice a day]"
>>> re.sub("[\(\[].*?[\)\]]", "", x)
'This is a sentence.  '
```

Important: This code will not work with nested symbols

#### Explanation

The first regex groups `(` or `[` into group 1 (by surrounding it with parentheses) and `)` or `]` into group 2, matching these groups and all characters that come in between them. After matching, the matched portion is substituted with groups 1 and 2, leaving the final string with nothing inside the brackets. The second regex is self explanatory from this -> match everything and substitute with the empty string.

*-- modified from [comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14596884/remove-text-between-and#comment86784588_14599280) by [Ajay Thomas](https://stackoverflow.com/users/5459912/ajay-thomas)*

Comment: it doesn't work if `x = "ewq[a [(b] ([c))]]"`, it gives `'ewq )]]'` not `'eqw'`...

Comment: @paddila I know but Tic does not say anything about nested symbols.

Comment: I commented asking him about it.. he hasn't responded yet

Comment: can someone explain the regex used here?

Comment: @markroxor the first regex groups '(' and ']' into group 1(by surrounding it with parentheses) and ')' and ']' into group 2., matching these groups and all characters that come in between the two groups. After matching, the matched portion is substituted with groups 1 and  2, leaving the final string with nothing inside the brackets. 
The second regex is self explanatory from this -> match everything and substitute with empty string. Hope it helps

Answer (score 30):

Run this script, it works even with nested brackets.
Uses basic logical tests.

```
def a(test_str):
    ret = ''
    skip1c = 0
    skip2c = 0
    for i in test_str:
        if i == '[':
            skip1c += 1
        elif i == '(':
            skip2c += 1
        elif i == ']' and skip1c > 0:
            skip1c -= 1
        elif i == ')'and skip2c > 0:
            skip2c -= 1
        elif skip1c == 0 and skip2c == 0:
            ret += i
    return ret

x = "ewq[a [(b] ([c))]] This is a sentence. (once a day) [twice a day]"
x = a(x)
print x
print repr(x)
```

Just incase you don't run it,
Here's the output:

```
>>> 
ewq This is a sentence.  
'ewq This is a sentence.  '
```

Answer (score 20):

Here's a solution similar to [@pradyunsg's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14598135/4279) (it works with arbitrary nested brackets):

```
def remove_text_inside_brackets(text, brackets="()[]"):
    count = [0] * (len(brackets) // 2) # count open/close brackets
    saved_chars = []
    for character in text:
        for i, b in enumerate(brackets):
            if character == b: # found bracket
                kind, is_close = divmod(i, 2)
                count[kind] += (-1)**is_close # `+1`: open, `-1`: close
                if count[kind] < 0: # unbalanced bracket
                    count[kind] = 0  # keep it
                else:  # found bracket to remove
                    break
        else: # character is not a [balanced] bracket
            if not any(count): # outside brackets
                saved_chars.append(character)
    return ''.join(saved_chars)

print(repr(remove_text_inside_brackets(
    "This is a sentence. (once a day) [twice a day]")))
# -> 'This is a sentence.  '
```

Comment: Looks complex at first glance, but is better than mine (and definitely the accepted (my opinion))

Comment: Excellent answer.

Answer (score 8):

You can split, filter, and join the string again. If your brackets are well defined the following code should do.

```python
import re
x = "".join(re.split("\(|\)|\[|\]", x)[::2])
```

Comment: Very late, but very better. :-P

Comment: Just what I needed - short and sweet!

Comment: Just know this also doesn't work on something like "A((B))C"

Answer (score 5):

You can try this. Can remove the bracket and the content exist inside it.

```
 import re
    x = "This is a sentence. (once a day) [twice a day]"
    x = re.sub("\(.*?\)|\[.*?\]","",x)
    print(x)
```

Expected ouput :

```
This is a sentence.
```

Answer (score 3):

For anyone who appreciates the simplicity of the accepted answer by jvallver, and is looking for more readability from their code:

```
>>> import re
>>> x = 'This is a sentence. (once a day) [twice a day]'
>>> opening_braces = '\(\['
>>> closing_braces = '\)\]'
>>> non_greedy_wildcard = '.*?'
>>> re.sub(f'[{opening_braces}]{non_greedy_wildcard}[{closing_braces}]', '', x)
'This is a sentence.  '
```

Most of the explanation for why this regex works is included in the code. Your future self will thank you for the 3 additional lines.

(Replace the f-string with the equivalent string concatenation for Python2 compatibility)

Answer (score 0):

The RegEx `\(.*?\)|\[.*?\]` removes bracket content by finding pairs, first it remove paranthesis and then square brackets. I also works fine for the nested brackets as it acts in sequence. Ofcourse, it would break in case of bad brackets scenario.

```py
    _brackets = re.compile("\(.*?\)|\[.*?\]")
    _spaces = re.compile("\s+")
    
    _b = _brackets.sub(" ", "microRNAs (miR) play a role in cancer ([1], [2])")
    _s = _spaces.sub(" ", _b.strip())
    print(_s)
    
    # OUTPUT: microRNAs play a role in cancer
```

Answer (score 0):

A solution without regex that doesn't care about balanced parenthesis (left to right associates to the nearest open close pair) and adds remainders to the end if unclosed and immediately begins to remove characters if they're after a open parentheses no matter the number of previous closed parentheses.

```
def removeparenthesis(input_str, open_p="(", close_p=")"):
    result = ''
    remainder = ''
    paren_level = 0
    for ch in input_str:
        if ch in open_p:
            if paren_level < 0:
                paren_level = 1
            else:
                paren_level += 1
        elif ch in close_p:
            paren_level -= 1
            remainder = ''
        elif 0 >= paren_level:
            result += ch
        else:
            remainder += ch
    return result + remainder
```

I find it a bit more natural than forcing everything to be balanced. Extra close parentheses are made for ignoring in text in the wild

It helps if your usecase is removing parenthesis and their contents, to not be left with awkward unmatched ones. The 'safe' way to call this is probably two calls one for each pair instead of one with both pairs though, since I didn't find a way I liked to do both without matching a (] or similar, even if the option is there.