# How to remove all text between the outer parentheses in a string?

Tags: python, regex, parentheses

When I have a string like this:

```
s1 = 'stuff(remove_me)'
```

I can easily remove the parentheses and the text within using

```
# returns 'stuff'
res1 = re.sub(r'\([^)]*\)', '', s1)
```

as explained [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/640001/how-can-i-remove-text-within-parentheses-with-a-regex).

But I sometimes encounter nested expressions like this:

```
s2 = 'stuff(remove(me))'
```

When I run the command from above, I end up with

```
'stuff)'
```

I also tried:

```
re.sub('\(.*?\)', '', s2)
```

which gives me the same output.

How can I remove everything within the outer parentheses - including the parentheses themselves - so that I also end up with `'stuff'` (which should work for arbitrarily complex expressions)?

Comment: Check [*Remove text between () and \[\] in python*](http://stackoverflow.com/a/14598135/3832970).

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew: Thanks! But that is about expressions which are not nested. And I am pretty sure that there exists something which does not require a lot of if-else clauses and a for-loop.

Comment: This [answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/12280660/3832970) contains the regex you need but you need a PyPi regex module.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`re` matches are eager so they try to match as much text as possible, for the simple test case you mention just let the regex run:

```
>>> re.sub(r'\(.*\)', '', 'stuff(remove(me))')
'stuff'
```

Comment: @Cleb be warned that this doesn't check if the braces are matched. E.g. in `foo(bar)baz(spam)e)ggs`, it'll leave only `fooggs`.

Comment: @ivan_pozdeev: Thanks for the warning, good to know! In my examples they should be matched but I'll add a check anyway.

Comment: The problem isn't only with matching parentheses but also with text between groups of parentheses: `'foo(bar)baz(spam)'` turns into `'foo'` instead of `'foobaz'`

Answer (score 19):

**NOTE**: `\(.*\)` matches the first `(` from the left, then matches any 0+ characters (other than a newline if a DOTALL modifier is not enabled) up to the *last* `)`, and does not account for properly nested parentheses.

**To remove nested parentheses correctly with a regular expression in Python**, you may use a simple [`\([^()]*\)`](https://regex101.com/r/cQfh5r/2) (matching a `(`, then 0+ chars other than `(` and `)` and then a `)`) in a *while* block using [`re.subn`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/re.html#re.subn):

```
def remove_text_between_parens(text):
    n = 1  # run at least once
    while n:
        text, n = re.subn(r'\([^()]*\)', '', text)  # remove non-nested/flat balanced parts
    return text
```

Bascially: remove the `(...)` with no `(` and `)` inside until no match is found. Usage:

```
print(remove_text_between_parens('stuff (inside (nested) brackets) (and (some(are)) here) here'))
# => stuff   here
```

A non-regex way is also possible:

```
def removeNestedParentheses(s):
    ret = ''
    skip = 0
    for i in s:
        if i == '(':
            skip += 1
        elif i == ')'and skip > 0:
            skip -= 1
        elif skip == 0:
            ret += i
    return ret

x = removeNestedParentheses('stuff (inside (nested) brackets) (and (some(are)) here) here')
print(x)              
# => 'stuff   here'
```

See [another Python demo](https://ideone.com/2ZhSYQ)

Comment: Just in case one needs to use the `re` approach to remove nested square brackets, use `r'\[[^][]*]'` pattern. For curly braces, use `r'{[^{}]*}'`

Answer (score 6):

As mentioned before, you'd need a [recursive regex](http://www.rexegg.com/regex-recursion.html) for matching arbitrary levels of nesting but if you know there can only be a maximum of one level of nesting have a try with this pattern:

```
\((?:[^)(]|\([^)(]*\))*\)
```

- `[^)(]` matches a character, that is not a parenthesis ([negated class](http://www.regular-expressions.info/charclass.html#negated)).
- `|\([^)(]*\)` or it matches another `(` `)` pair with any amount of *non* `)(` inside.
- `(?:`...`)*` all this any amount of times inside `(` `)`

[Here is a demo at regex101](https://regex101.com/r/yM8bO4/1)

Before the alternation used `[^)(]` without `+` quantifier to fail faster if unbalanced.
You need to add more levels of nesting that might occure. Eg for max 2 levels:

```
\((?:[^)(]|\((?:[^)(]|\([^)(]*\))*\))*\)
```

[Another demo at regex101](https://regex101.com/r/wV8nF7/1)

Comment: Very nice, thanks for the detailed explanation (upvoted)!

Comment: I just came across a similar situation and searched a lot for this solution. Thanks for sharing this idea with good explanation.

Answer (score 1):

If you are sure that the parentheses are initially balanced, just use the *greedy* version:

```
re.sub(r'\(.*\)', '', s2)
```

Comment: Undesired effect: text between groups of parentheses gets deleted, for example `'foo(bar)baz(spam)'` turns into `'foo'` instead of `'foobaz'`

Answer (score 1):

https://regex101.com/r/kQ2jS3/1

```
'(\(.*\))'
```

This captures the `furthest` parentheses, and everything in between the parentheses.

Your old regex captures the first parentheses, and everything between to the `next` parentheses.

Comment: Same as the other two answer but thanks anyway (upvoted)... :)

Comment: Undesired effect: text between groups of parentheses gets deleted, for example `'foo(bar)baz(spam)'` turns into `'foo'` instead of `'foobaz'`

Answer (score 0):

I have found a solution here:

http://rachbelaid.com/recursive-regular-experession/

which says:

```
>>> import regex
>>> regex.search(r"^(\((?1)*\))(?1)*$", "()()") is not None
True
>>> regex.search(r"^(\((?1)*\))(?1)*$", "(((()))())") is not None
True
>>> regex.search(r"^(\((?1)*\))(?1)*$", "()(") is not None
False
>>> regex.search(r"^(\((?1)*\))(?1)*$", "(((())())") is not None
False
```

Answer (score 0):

## No Python loops. No recursion. No regexes.

Just computing the difference between the cumulative counts of `'('` and `')'`:

```
import numpy as np
s = '()a(x(x)x)b(x)c()d()'
s_array = np.array(list(s))
mask_open = s_array=='('
mask_close = s_array==')'
# Compute in how many parentheses each character is nested,
# while considering ')' as not nested:
nestedness_except_close = np.cumsum(mask_open) - np.cumsum(mask_close)
# ... and while considering ')' as nested:
nestedness = nestedness_except_close + mask_close
# Select only characters that aren't in any parentheses
result = ''.join(s_array[nestedness < 1])
```

This might be faster than other solutions.

Optional validity checks for the string:

```
# Check whether the number of `'('`s and `')'`s is the same
assert(nestedness_except_close[-1] == 0)
# Check whether some parentheses get closed before they got opened
assert((nestedness_except_close >= 0).all())
```

If you don't want to use NumPy, you can use [`itertools.accumulate()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.accumulate) to compute the cumulative sums.

Comment: Further speedups might be achieved by passing `0` as a second argument to `np.cumsum()`. An approach like `s_array = np.frombuffer(s.encode('utf-8'), dtype=np.uint8)` can also be tried.