# To remove strings in between quotes and inserting a new line before a special character from a text file and saving it

Tags: python, text-files

I am trying to read a text file and remove anything in between quotes ("") and also any kind of commas and semi-colons.

I also want to insert a line before the string of characters 'qwe'.

I have no experience with python and I have been tasked to this in python.

Comment: It's easy tho...

Comment: If you have no experience, RTM and try it yourself :D If you get in any trouble, show what you tried and we will help

Comment: Okay! thanks for the help @ThomasDussaut what do you mean by RTM?

Comment: check [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14596884/remove-text-between-and-in-python)

Comment: Read The Manual --> check any documentation source ;)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Remove text between () and \[\] in python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14596884/remove-text-between-and-in-python)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
import re
with open('code.txt', 'r') as infile, open('noquotes.txt', 'w') as outfile:
    for line in infile:
        x=''
        line=re.sub('".+?"', '', line)
        for i in range(len(line)):
            if str(line[i])!=',':
                x+=str(line[i])
            if str(line[i])== ',':
                pass
    outfile.write(x)
    outfile.close(x)
```

I got it :D

Answer (score 0):

```
f = open('filename.txt', 'r')
for line in f:
    x=''
    for i in range(len(line)):
        if str(line[i]) != ',':
            x += str(line[i])
        if str(line[i]) == ',':
            pass
print (x)
```

Here's some example code to read and remove comma's from a text file, you can start from this and try adding all the other stuff you want to do. Just have this code saved in the same place as the text file and type the text file's name where it says filename.