# Remove all types of brackets in a string in python (with content)

Tags: python, python-3.x, regex

I have a string which contains multiple types of brackets

```
strng="example - example [Bracket one] middle text to be retained (second bracket) example {third one}"
```

should become

```
"example - example middle text to be retained example"
```

So, I tried to use regular expressions but since I am using groups for different bracket types, the substitution works only if the brackets are side by side. As stated below:

```
pattern=re.compile(r'((\[|\().*(\]|\)))')
print(re.sub(pattern,"", strng))
```

How do I fix this problem?

Comment: Check this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14596884/remove-text-between-and-in-python/14598135

Comment: If you are open for none regex based solutions, here is one I wrote https://pastebin.com/JLJSDiz9 It might require some testing and tweaks I'll leave it up for you!

Comment: https://www.kite.com/python/answers/how-to-remove-multiple-characters-from-a-string-in-python