# Python - How do i delete more than one character on python using slice method, find and rfind

Tags: python

I need some help in removing two sets of curly brackets with string.Right now it's only removing one set. I tired to use find and rfind to find the first and last occurence of the string index and using slice method to cut out the curly brackets but it can only remove one set of it.

It should work something like that

**Input:** {fefeef}this{feofeow}.4849

**Output** this.4849

Here is my code

```
 def help_mmtf():
    
       while True:
    
           user_input = input("Filename?")
           text_input = str(user_input)
    
           if (text_input !=""):
               
    
                word = text_input
                
                index1 = word.find("{")
                index2 = word.find("}")
                print(index1) 
                print(index2)
    
            
                index3 = word.rfind("{")
                index4 = word.rfind("}")
    
                print(index3)
                print(index4)
               
    
                splice_input = text_input[:index1] + text_input[index4+1:]
                print(f'"{splice_input}"')
    
      else:
               
                
               break
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Remove text between () and \[\]](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14596884/remove-text-between-and)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `sub`

```
import re


def help_mmtf():
    while True:

        user_input = input("Filename?")
        text_input = str(user_input)

        if (text_input != ""):
            word = text_input



            splice_input = re.sub("\{.*?\}", "", word)
            print(f'"{splice_input}"')

        else:


         break
```

**Time complexity: O(2^m + n).**

or you can use the for loop

```
def help_mmtf():
    while True:

        user_input = input("Filename?")
        text_input = str(user_input)

        if (text_input != ""):
            splice_input = ''

            paren = 0
            for ch in text_input:


                if ch == '{':
                    paren = paren + 1
                    splice_input = splice_input

              
        
                elif (ch == '}') and paren:
                    splice_input = splice_input
                    paren = paren - 1

                elif not paren:
                    splice_input += ch

            print(splice_input)

        else:


         break
```

**Time complexity: O(n).**

Answer (score 4):

Use `sub` function from `re` module:

```
import re

s = "{fefeef}this{feofeow}.4849"
out = re.sub(r'{[^}]*}', '', s)
```

Output:

```
>>> out
'this.4849'
```

For more explanation: [Regex101](https://regex101.com/r/SPOteR/1)